# How to represent a data set in latex?

Tags: tables, formatting

I have below data.I would like to upload into latex doc in the below format.

```
Length Left Right Bottom Top Diagonal
214.8 131.0 131.1 9.0 9.7 141.0
214.6 129.7 129.7 8.1 9.5 141.7
214.8 129.7 129.7 8.7 9.6 142.2
214.8 129.7 129.6 7.5 10.4 142.0
215.0 129.6 129.7 10.4 7.7 141.8
214.4 130.1 130.3 9.7 11.7 139.8
214.9 130.5 130.2 11.0 11.5 139.5
214.9 130.3 130.1 8.7 11.7 140.2
215.0 130.4 130.6 9.9 10.9 140.3
214.7 130.2 130.3 11.8 10.9 139.7
...
...
...
...
...
...
```

Comment: can you tell what you have tried and what the problem is? answer to many of your questions are just a google search away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread{
Length Left Right Bottom Top Diagonal
214.8 131.0 131.1 9.0 9.7 141.0
214.6 129.7 129.7 8.1 9.5 141.7
214.8 129.7 129.7 8.7 9.6 142.2
214.8 129.7 129.6 7.5 10.4 142.0
215.0 129.6 129.7 10.4 7.7 141.8
214.4 130.1 130.3 9.7 11.7 139.8
214.9 130.5 130.2 11.0 11.5 139.5
214.9 130.3 130.1 8.7 11.7 140.2
215.0 130.4 130.6 9.9 10.9 140.3
214.7 130.2 130.3 11.8 10.9 139.7
}\mytable
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[fixed, %number format
zerofill, %remove if you don't want integers having .0 suffix
precision=1, %how many digits needed for decimal part
dec sep align %align at the decimal point
]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]